# SQL Server 2005 Failover Cluster Using One Server?

Tags: .net, sql-server, sql-server-2005, cluster-computing, failover

I am developing an application that is hosted on a SQL Server 2005 failover cluster.  The application (developed using C#, .Net 2.0) makes use of a number of the clustered resources (printers, file shares, etc).  I would like to set up a testing environment that replicates the cluster.  However, the current test environment has only one SQL server, and there is no hope of ever getting a second server to create a full cluster.  Is there some way I can mock the cluster environment using only a single server?

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Many thanks, MagicAndi.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use virtual machines. I had used MS Virtual Server and R2 for this, it has support for creating a virtual cluster. I've been doing this a lot of times when I had to test against clusters and make sure my code survives fail overs gracefully.

The whole process is a bit convoluted, as you will need to create a virtual private network and have the two virtual hosts share a virtual SCSI drive for the cluster, but fortunately there are good step by step guides out there. Here is a good one: http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/virtualserver/deploy/cvs2005.mspx

Once you have your cluster up and running, go ahead and install a clustered SQL instance on it, the process is exactly as you would do it on a real metal cluster.

Comment: BTW the free MS Virtual PC does NOT support virtual clusters

Comment: And even more useful for testing is that you can run your tests, observe and log the results, then revert the virtual images to the pre-test conditions every time.

Comment: Remus, Thanks for the link and information, it is much appreciated. +1

Answer (score 2):

It just so happens that SQL Server Central posted an article on this today: Setting up a [SQL cluster under MS VS2005 R2 Part1, By Perry Whittle](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Clustering/65994/)

Comment: MS Virtual Server is really easy to use to set up clustering, though if you aren't on a domain, you'll also need to create a virtual DC.

Comment: Cade, Thanks for the link, +1.

Answer (score 0):

I would think that you would be able to achieve it through OS virtualization.

Answer (score 0):

About the only potential option would be to set up virtual machines on the one server.  Honestly, however, I don't know if MS clutering supports using virtual machines as cluster nodes.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it, but you could try installing another instance of sql server on the server.

Answer (score 0):

No, MS clustering do supports using virtual machines as cluster nodes....and its a good option to use virtual machines for to test your cluster environment if the physical machine has a good resources.